# Consulta Where PHP

Tags: php, web, xampp

Quisiera saber por que no me anda esta parte del código. Estoy probando usando una base en phpMyAdmin en xampp.

```
$conexion=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=personas',"root", "");

$consultaa = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * WHERE Cuil=:cuil")
$consultaa->execute(array(
    ':cuil' => $xcuil
));
if ($xcuil=mysql_fetch_array($consultaa)) {
    echo "<script> alert("Cuil ya Ingresado") </script>";
    exit();
}
```

Comment: me sigue sin agarra..

Comment: error=    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$consultaa' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\nuevositio2\personass.php on line 17

Comment: si te fijas tu sintaxis esta asi: "SELECT * WHERE Cuil=:cuil"

Comment: debes especificar tu tabla "SELECT  *  FROM mi_tabla WHERE Cuil=:cuil"

Comment: ahora me salta error en la funcion "mysql_fetch_array"

Comment: te recomiendo que leas la documentacion y ejemplos: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: Estás **mezclando** código. Esta función `mysql_fetch_array` no es de PDO. Y aparte de eso es una función obsoleta. Revisa [los métodos `fetch` de PDO en el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php). Allí hay ejemplos claros de como se usan .

Comment: Trata en lo posible de ser más descriptivo en tus variables para que cuando debas dar posterior mantenimiento al sistema (o un tercero) puedas ubicarte rápidamente en el código y solventar/mejorar lo que se necesites. Un saludo